# Would being connected to two networks increase bandwidth/speed up access?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

So I recently saw a video on ethernet cable hacks in which it demonstrated making a network cable where the computer could be connected to two networks at once. I've seen the same concept in phones using dual network cards.

My question is, would the OS split the requests over the two networks somehow, making the whole process faster?

Is there an advantage to being connected to two networks at once?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few possible ways this can be done - it would likely prefer one connection over the other (so it acts as a poor man's failover) by default. The advantage of this is reliability - if one line is troublesome you can switch over to the other one

If both ends of the connection support it, you can use [channel bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_bonding), and use both physical connections together like a single connection. Chances are if you need to ask whether you can use it, you can't - its generally supported on higher end, enterprise grade equipment

You could also run some load balancing software - [dispatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/) (Windows only, there's a limited, free version and a pro version with a ton of useful features) or [dispatch proxy](https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy) (free, runs anywhere node.js runs) which won't help with single threaded speeds (say *one* website) but will help with multithreaded speeds by spreading your bandwidth between many connections. Dispatch has a UI, and very fine grained controls on which connections to use. Dispatch proxy is simple, dosen't let you do more than set which interfaces to use, and to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can (sometimes, it probably violates the standards and might degrade performance) use unused conductors in a network cable to carry an additional connection (won't work for 1000BASE-T obviously, since all conductors are needed). This is utilizing extra pairs of wire in the physical cable - not actually using a single network adapter for two connections.

It's possible for example to bond two internet connections to create a single faster one (for example, [on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53499/how-to-merge-multiple-internet-connections-into-one)). It doesn't happen automatically, however; you have to configure the connections properly.